# Can you do a Form submission with Javascript disable

Tags: asp.net, forms, form-submit, javascript

If a user has disabled Javascript in their client browser and they try to use a Form on the Web Page, this causes a Postback.  My understanding is that the Form would create a Javascript function `__doPostBack` to handle the Form submission, but with Javascript disabled a normal Postback occurs.  When checking what as been posted back to the server, the Form is empty.  Can a Form work with Javascript disabled?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A form ABSOLUTELY works without Javascript.

Just put your form consumption code in the [button click event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.button.click.aspx).

something like this perhaps

```
void btnSubmit_Click(Object sender,
                       EventArgs e)
{
    // When the button is clicked,
    // send the values of the input fields to the database.

}
```

Answer (score 0):

The form will be submitted without javascript.

Any client-side validation will not run, so you may have invalid data.  This is why you always, always perform server-side validation of your forms.

Now, you state that your form is empty.  If you depend on javascript, jquery, or some other client-side programming to set values in your fields, then you may see empty values.  I'm not sure where you're checking, but if you take a look at the request object in your page_load, you should see your data there.